# How to search across all the fields?

Tags: lucene.net, lucene

In Lucene, we can use TermQuery to search a text with a field. I am wondering how to search a keyword across a bunch of fields or all the searchable fields?

Answer (score 29):

Another approach, which doesn't require to index anything more than what you already have, nor to combine different queries, is using the [`MultiFieldQueryParser`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/queryparser/index.html).

You can provide a list of fields where you want to search on and your query, that's all.

```
MultiFieldQueryParser queryParser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(
                Version.LUCENE_41, 
                new String[]{"title", "content", "description"},
                new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_41));

Query query = queryParser.parse("here goes your query");
```

This is how I would do it with the original lucene library written in Java. I'm not sure whether the `MultiFieldQueryParser` is available in lucene.net too.

Comment: MultiFieldQueryParser  is an elegant approach.. :)

Comment: Thanks, your answer is not bad either ;) +1

Comment: It is, at least in 4.8 (the latest as of this Comment), in Lucene.Net - it's in the Lucene.Net.QueryParser Project, under the Classic folder.

Answer (score 11):

Two approaches

1) Index-time approach: Use a *catch-all* field. This is nothing but appending all the text from all the fields (total text from your input doc) and place that resulting huge text in a single field. You've to add an additional field while indexing to act as a catch-all field.

2) Search-time approach: Use a [BooleanQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/BooleanQuery.html) to combine multiple queries, for example TermQuery instances. Those multiple queries can be formed to cover all the target fields.

[Example](http://www.lucenetutorial.com/lucene-query-syntax.html) check at the end of the article.

Use approach 2 if you know the target-field list at runtime. Otherwise, you've got to use the 1st approach.

Comment: Thanks for good big picture explanation. The first approach is what I use when storing different types of products in same index, for example Printers versus Monitors, where different fields exist for each doc but I want to use "full-text" search with a simple search string and bring back all products that match.

Answer (score 5):

Another easy approach to search across all fields using "[MultifieldQueryParser](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/queryparser/index.html)" is use **IndexReader.FieldOption.ALL** in your query.

Here is example in c#.

```
Directory directory = FSDirectory.Open(new DirectoryInfo(HostingEnvironment.MapPath(VirtualIndexPath)));

    //get analyzer
    Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_29);

    //get index reader and searcher
    IndexReader indexReader__1 = IndexReader.Open(directory, true);
    Searcher indexSearch = new IndexSearcher(indexReader__1);

    //add all possible fileds in multifieldqueryparser using indexreader getFieldNames method
    var queryParser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(Version.LUCENE_29, indexReader__1.GetFieldNames(IndexReader.FieldOption.ALL).ToArray(), analyzer);
    var query = queryParser.Parse(Criteria);
    TopDocs resultDocs = null;

    //perform search
    resultDocs = indexSearch.Search(query, indexReader__1.MaxDoc());
    var hits = resultDocs.scoreDocs;
```

[click here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10910110/284225) to check out my pervious answer to same quesiton in vb.net

Comment: I don't see the point of using duck typing here (i.e. `dynamic` keyword). Maybe you wanted to use type interence with `var`?